# How do I make a Toplevel widget appear and disapear

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a GUI that has two Toplevel widgets and a root frame, where I wish for one of the Toplevel widgets to be invisible when I initiate the GUI but which can be made to be seen by clicking a button in the root frame. I can insert the line:

```
win2.withdraw()
```

in the start_window code (which builds the entire GUI) which will make the Toplevel widget invisible when the GUI is initialized, but I can't figure out how to re-draw the Toplevel widget once I want it to be visible. I expected the command:

```
win2.deiconify()
```

to provide the desired functionality but I get the following error message when I attempt this:

```
AttributeError: start_window instance has no attribute 'deiconify'
```

Here is my code, which when mainloop()ed, creates the GUI. I have two separate widget classes that I am using in this code, one is for a ScrolledList widget and the second is for a ScrolledText widget. It is the ScrolledText widget I wish to be invisible when I initiate the GUI and then by clicking a button on the root frame that makes the ScrolledText widget visible.

```
class start_window(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    #self.pa()
    Frame.pack(self)
    win1 = Toplevel()
    win2 = Toplevel()
    Label(self, text = 'Bioasys DataBase', width = 30).pack()
    btn = Button(self, text='Make Widget Visible', command=win2.master.deiconify())
    btn.pack(side=TOP)
    win1.title('Company Lookup')
    win2.title('Company Information')
    ScrolledList(win1).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    #stock_sym = 'acad'

    #text1, text2 = create_company_information(stock_sym)


    try:
        stco_name = ScrolledText(win2, file=sys.argv[1], width= 50, height=15).pack()
    except IndexError:
        #text1 = 'Company Name - Company Symbol\n\nCompany URL\n\nCompany Address Line 1\nCompany Address Line 2\ncompany Address Line 3\nCompany Address Line 4'
        stco_name = ScrolledText(win2, text= text1, width= 50, height=15).pack()

    try:
        stco_sym = ScrolledText(win2,file=sys.argv[1], width=50, height=15).pack()
    except IndexError:
        #text2 = 'Company Description'
        stco_sym = ScrolledText(win2, text= text2, width=50, height=15).pack()

    win2.withdraw()  # makes the win2 frame invisible at startup
    #win2.pack_forget()
    #win2.master.deiconify()
```

Here is the code for the two different Toplevel widgets, these widget classes both work correctly. I am including this code so that the start_window class can be made to function properly.

```
class ScrolledList(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    self.makeWidgets()
def handleList(self, event):
    index = self.listbox.curselection()
    label = self.listbox.get(index)
    self.runCommand(label)
def fetch(self):
    print 'Input => "%s"' % self.ent.get()

def makeWidgets(self):
    self.ent = Entry(self)
    btn = Button(self, text='ENTER', command=self.fetch)
    sbar = Scrollbar(self)
    list = Listbox(self, relief=SUNKEN)
    self.ent.insert(0, 'Type Stock Symbol Here')
    self.ent.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    self.ent.focus()
    self.ent.bind('<Return>', (lambda event: self.fetch()))
    value = self.ent.get()
    btn.pack(side=TOP)
    sbar.config(command=list.yview)
    list.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
    sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    options_init = open_pickled_company_list()  #
    options = [i[1] for i in options_init]      #
    for label in options:
        list.insert('end', label)
    #list.config(selectmode=SINGLE, setgrid=1)
    list.bind('<Double-1>', self.handleList)
    self.listbox = list


def runCommand(self, selection):
    print 'You selected: ', selection
    self.ent.delete(0, END)
    self.ent.insert(0, selection)



class ScrolledText(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent=None, text='', file=None, width='', height=''):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)                # make me expandable
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.makewidgets()
    self.settext(text, file)
def makewidgets(self):
    sbar = Scrollbar(self)
    text = Text(self, relief=SUNKEN, width=self.width, height=self.height)
    sbar.config(command=text.yview)                  # xlink sbar and text
    text.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)             # move one moves other
    sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                    # pack first=clip last
    text.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)      # text clipped first
    self.text = text
def settext(self, text='', file=None):
    if file: 
        text = open(file, 'r').read()
    self.text.delete('1.0', END)                     # delete current text
    self.text.insert('1.0', text)                    # add at line 1, col 0
    self.text.mark_set(INSERT, '1.0')                # set insert cursor
    self.text.focus()                                # save user a click
def gettext(self):                                   # returns a string
    return self.text.get('1.0', END+'-1c')           # first through last
```

And here is the mainloop() command that intiates the GUI:

```
start_window().mainloop()
```

So to summarize I am looking to start my GUI with an invisible Toplevel Win2 widget but by clicking a button on the root frame the Win2 widget can be made visible. If anybody has any ideas on how to accomplish this I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I expected the command: `win2.deiconify()` to provide the desired
>   functionality but I get the following error message when I attempt
>   this:
>
> AttributeError: start_window instance has no attribute 'deiconify'

What you say and what the error message says are two different things. You are not calling `win2.deiconify()` but rather `start_window.deiconify()`.

`win2.deiconify()` is indeed how you make an invisible toplevel window visible, assuming that `win2` is a reference to an instance of `Toplevel`.

The solution involves saving a reference to the toplevel window so that you can reference it in the callback. For example:

class start_window(Frame):
    def **init**(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.win2 = Toplevel()
        ...
        btn = Button(self, text='Make Widget Visible', command=self.win2.deiconify)

You have another subtle bug in your code. Note that in the original code you have `command=self.win2.master.deiconif())`. The `command` attribute takes a reference to a function. Instead, you're calling the `deiconify` method, and whatever that returns is being assigned to the `command` attribute. You have the further complication that self.win2 doesn't have a `master` attribute.

The solution is to set the `command` attribute to `self.win2` (eg: `command=self.win2.deiconify)`)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I understand that the start_window is a Frame subclass and hence (according to the error message) doesn't have the deiconify method, what I don't understand how to do is get the deiconify method to work in my current code setup. Do I need to not make my start_window class a subclass of Frame? Thanks for your help. Sincerely, George

Comment: The error message may be saying "start_window instance has no attribute 'deiconify'" but the command I am using is "command=win2.master.deiconify()" (the master portion is a typo, the command I am using is actually win2.deiconify()). So I don't understand why I am specifying win2 but the error message is specifying start_window. It is true that the button/command I am using is within start_window but isn't it possible to control one aspect of a Gui (in this case win2) from within the root frame (in this case the start_window subclassed to Frame)? I appreciate your help. Sincerely, George

Comment: @user3798654: you should double-check your code. Python errors usually don't lie. If it says there's an error with `start_window.deiconify()`, it's safe to assume that's exactly what code was called.

Comment: @user3798654: if win2 is an attribute of `start_window`, you can call `start_window.win2.deiconify()`. As posted, however, `win2` is a local variable that is inaccessible outside `__init__`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your response. When I make the change you suggest I get the following error message: AttributeError: class start_window has no attribute 'win2'. So I guess the question is how do I make win2 a variable that is accessible outside __init__? Sincerely, George

Comment: @user3798654: do `self.win2 = win2` or avoid the local variable altogether and always use `self.win2` (eg: `self.win2 = Toplevel()` ... `self.win2.title(...)` ...)

Comment: I tried changing every instance of win2 to self.win2 within the start_window code but when I run the start_window code I get the GUI with the root Frame and the Win1 Toplevel widget visible but if I click the root frame button to deiconify win2 nothing happens to win2 (it is not made visible). Sincerely, George

Comment: @user3798654: I've updated my answer. You have additional bugs I didn't notice when I first wrote my answer.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thank you very much, your suggestions work perfectly and the win2 Toplevel widget can now be made to reappear as desired. Thanks Again, George